# Issue with Express Checkout for Digital Goods on the Sandbox..?

Tags: paypal

I'm working with Express Checkout for digital goods.  I have some old projects that I did in the past that were working fine, and I'm also working on a new project now in the sandbox.

On my old projects (which worked fine when I originally built them) and the current project I'm getting "Bad Request" back in the browser window when attempting to redirect to the digital goods server.

For example, the SetExpressCheckout call works just fine, but then when I try to redirect to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?useraction=continue&token=EC-0XT42801HU928651A I get the following:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Size of a request header field exceeds server limit. Cookie /n

If I run the exact same thing, though, without the digital goods Javascript and using the regular redirect URL it works just fine.

Any information on what I'm doing wrong or what's changed here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with this in the past.  In the past clearing your cookies and cache would temporarily resolve the issue and would allow for testing.  Do you still getting this error after clearing your cookies and cache and retrying the checkout?  If you are still getting an error after doing this, please open up a ticket with [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](http://www.paypal.com/mts), so that we can look into the cause of the issue.